# Update the flot graph by changing plot data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I want to update a flot graph by changing one value in the series and corresponding plots also should be updated based on the changed value. My x-axis is date and time and my y-axis is the count.

[image: Sample image]

In the above image its explained what exactly i want.

```
function fnUpdateGraph(isNew,isUndo,isRedo){
 if(selectednodeid==undefined){
  showdialog(message.information,messages.informatio,"No nodes selected",null,false);
  return false;
 }
 var newHeadDate=new Date();
 var updateDate=document.getElementById("txt_node_head_date").value.split("-",3);
 newHeadDate.setDate(updateDate[0]);
 newHeadDate.setDate(+updateDate[1]-1);
 newHeadDate.setDate(updateDate[2]);
 var updateTime=document.getElementById("txt_node_head_time").value.split(":",2);
 newHeadDate.setHours(updateTime[0],updatetime[1],0,0);
 var maxNodeId=vehicle[selectedvehicle].length;
 if(selectedNodeId<maxNodeID){
  if(newHeadDate.getTime()>=new Date(vehicle[selectedvehicle][selectedNodeId+1].headDate).getTime()){
   plot.setData();
   plot.setupGrid();
   plot.draw();
   return;
  }
 }
```

I have added a part of my code where I have defined the updateGraph function. What are the changes to be made in order to get the graph plotted with changed values.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. In your description above you keep saying plot, but I only see one plot, do you mean series?  Do you want to update all series based on a change to one series?  Can you code up a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Sir i meant data points sorry for the mistake. I meant in a series each data point if changed then flot graph has to be updated

Comment: In your code sample you have `plot.setData();`, are you asking how to use that method to insert a point into a series?

Comment: Sir for an instance if the point data is 31st DEC 2013 and time 11:23 then if user changes this value the graph should be plotted again  with newly changed data.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a combination of `plot.getData` and `plot.setData` (see docs [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods)).  `getData` will return an array of series, loop those until you find the point of interest and modify the value.  Then call `setData`, `setupGrid` and `draw`.

```
var someData = somePlot.getData();
// loop first series
for (var i = 0; i < someData[0].data.length; i++) {
  // the data member of the series contains x/y point data
  // look at X values until you find the one you want
  if (someData[0].data[i][0] == someSearchXValue) {
     someData[0].data[i][2] = someNewYValue;
     plot.setData(someData);
     plot.setupGrid();
     plot.draw();
     return;
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm6ea/).